# Need help to prevent parent onclick event when click on child div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to  to prevent parent onclick event when click on child div like that:

```html
<div onclick='parentClick()'>
  <div onclick='childClick()'>
    <div onlick='subchildClick()'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the **childClick()** function will do the **subchildClick()** function but prevent the **parentClick()**. How to do that?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `childClick` function use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation). Like this:

```
function childClick(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // Other stuff
}
```

`event.stopPropagation()` prevents the event from continuing to bubble up the DOM.
Because you're just calling this in the `childClick` handler the event from the `subChild` will still propagate up to the `childClick` handler.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the stopPropagation method of event.

```
function example(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```